# How to get height of Layout, fiiled with elements programmatically

Tags: android, layout, height

Hello to all programmers. While I create app for android, I met one problem. I want to create LinearLayout programmatically. Then I want to fill it with different elements programmatically. After that I want to get height of this LinearLayout to use it in future (for animation, for example) and set it's visibility to gone. All this actions I do in OnCreate of Activity, so if I try get height, I got 0.
Can anybody help me with this. All suggestions will be appreciated.

***UPDATED***

For *Gotiasits* and *Abbas* here the code

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.TestLayout);
    ScrollView contentScroll = FindViewById<ScrollView>(Resource.Id.contentScroll);
    LinearLayout contentContainer = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.contentContainer);
    List<DetailsData> dataList = new List<DetailsData>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        string header = "Header " + " " + i.ToString();
        string title = "Title " + i.ToString();
        string subtitle = "Subtitle";
        string pretext = "Some words in pretext. Some words in pretext. Some words in pretext. Some words in pretext. Some words in pretext. Some words in pretext.Some words in pretext. Some words in pretext.";
        int[] images = { Resource.Drawable.detail_main1, Resource.Drawable.detail_main2, Resource.Drawable.detail_main3, Resource.Drawable.detail_main1,
            Resource.Drawable.detail_main2, Resource.Drawable.detail_main3, Resource.Drawable.detail_main1 };
        string[] features =
        {
            "OSome words in featurelist.",
            "OSome words in featurelist.",
            "OSome words in featurelist.",
            "OSome words in featurelist.",
            "OSome words in featurelist.",
            "OSome words in featurelist.",
            "OSome words in featurelist.",
            "OSome words in featurelist.",
            "OSome words in featurelist.",
            "OSome words in featurelist.",
        };
        dataList.Add(new DetailsData(i, header, title, subtitle, pretext, features, images));
    }
    testContainer = new TestContaier(this, dataList, contentContainer, contentScroll, false);
    testContainer.DataBind();
}

class TestContaier
{
    Activity _context;
    public List<DetailsData> _dataSource { get; private set; }
    LinearLayout _mainLayout;
    ScrollView _scrollContainer;
    public TestContaier(Activity context, List<HotelDetailsData> dataSource,  LinearLayout mainLayout, ScrollView scrollContainer)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dataSource = dataSource;
        _mainLayout = mainLayout;
        _firstExpanded = firstExpanded;
        _scrollContainer = scrollContainer;
    }
    public void DataBind()
    {
        bool isFirst = true;
        if (_dataSource != null)
        {
            foreach (var _dataItem in _dataSource)
            {
                TextView header = new TextView(_context)
                {
                    Text = _dataItem._header
                };
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
                header.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(_settings._headerTextColor));
                header.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor(_settings._headerBackgroundColor));
                header.LayoutParameters = lp;

                View contentView = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DetailItem, null);
                ContentViewHolder holder = new ContentViewHolder();

                InitHolder(holder, contentView);

                FillHolder(holder, _dataItem);
                contentView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                holder.initialize(contentView);
                contentView.Tag = holder;
                header.AssociatedContent = contentView;
                _mainLayout.AddView(header);
                _mainLayout.AddView(contentView);
            }
        }
    }
    void InitHolder(ContentViewHolder holder, View view)
    {
        holder.imageSlider = view.FindViewById<ViewFlipper>(Resource.Id.imageSlider);
        holder.imagesContainer = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.scrollImagesContainer);
        holder.detailTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.detailTitle);
        holder.detailSubtitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.detailSubtitle);
        holder.detailPretext = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.detailPreText);
        holder.detailFeatureList = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.detailFeatureList);
        holder.nextSliderButton = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.nextSliderButton);
        holder.prevSliderButton = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.prevSliderButton);
    }
    void FillHolder(AccordionContentViewHolder holder, HotelDetailsData dataItem)
    {
        /// filling holder with data
    }
}
```

Comment: How and when did you access height?

Comment: It's because you should get height of the view when it is fully drawn like in `onResume()` not in `onCreate()`.

Comment: To @Abbas For example after render Layout on device screen. But not linked to any user actions. It should be done "automatically"

Comment: To @MaskedMan Nope, in OnResume() it shows 0 as in OnCreate.

Comment: @AdeptusMechanicus you still haven't shown the *How* i.e. the code.

Comment: @Abbas Added code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes some time for the linear layout to measure, pass to its children & correctly get its height. So you have to wait until its complete. Here is the code

**TRIED IT & WORKING: JAVA CODE**

```
    linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            int height = linearLayout.getMeasuredHeight();

            if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15){
                linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
```

You set-up a listener for the layout, after getting the height, unregister the `GlobalOnLayoutListener`

You can either use `linearLayout.getHeight()` or `linearLayout.getMeasuredHeight()`. Both provided the same values in my test

**XAMARIN CODE**

```
  ViewTreeObserver vto = _linearLayout.ViewTreeObserver;       
  vto.GlobalLayout += (sender, args) => {      
    var ht = linearLayout.Height;
   };
```

Comment: To @Ephraim Kigamba. Thanks for suggestion but, as you see, my code is C# (I use Visual Studio with Xamarin (not XamarinForms)). There are no such function as *getViewTreeObserver()* or property *ViewTreeObserver* for LinearLayout.

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that, this code will work on Java. BUt I have updated my code with XAMARIN CODE

Answer (score -1):

Your best guess would probably be that instead of trying to get hosting (LinearLayout) height, you can get the height of your child items and multiply it by the number of items in hosting View.

**EDIT**: Heres the solution which might get you what you need. This function can be called in both `onCreate()` and `onResume()`, as long it has access to initialized  `contentContainer`.

```
 public void getHeight(){

    contentContainer.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int sumHeight=0;
            for(int i=0; i<contentContainer.getChildCount(); i++){
                sumHeight+=contentContainer.getChildAt(i).getHeight();
            }
            Log.d("vidi", "Layout height = " + sumHeight);
        }
    });
```

Also as Masked Man nicely pointed out, if you have some padding or margins in your LinearLayout you can get them with ex. `contentContainer.getPaddingBottom` and add it to the sum.

The purpose of the `.post(Runnable)` is only to postpone code in Runnable, that is, queue this code to run after Layout has been drawn.

Comment: It is not correct as it can have padding and margin!

Comment: Padding and margin of ChildViews would be included in individual height. 
And I cannot see how would it make sense for a Hosting view to force margins.

Comment: No it's not best. As I sad - I create this elements programmatically and don't know their heights too.

Comment: Please supply your OnCreate method and we might be able to give you a more concrete explanation.
I tested getting the height for child views in mine application and it worked fine.
In my experience the way you're doing it, you'll always get either 0 or full-screen height.

Comment: @AdeptusMechanicus Did you manage to optimize proposed function for your code?